# strncat(): Random character in target string

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcat

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int ret = 0;

    char dirname[] = "test/";
    int path_maxlen = 256;
    char path[path_maxlen];
    int filename_maxlen = path_maxlen - strlen(dirname);

    strncat(path, dirname, path_maxlen - 1);

    strncat(path, "file.txt", filename_maxlen);

    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");

    printf("path: %s\n", path);

    if (file != NULL) {
        printf("success\n");

        fclose(file);
    } else {
        printf("fail\n");
        ret = 1;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This seemed to work at first but then it started to fail, i.e., the file could not be opened although it was present and no changes were made to the program or the file.

At that point I added the line that prints out `path`. After redirecting output to a file it turned out that `path` was preceded by a random character (ASCII: 1 SOH 'start of heading'). So I assume that `strncat` is not properly used here and some random junk gets written to my path array.

How do I correctly concatenate the strings in the above example?

**PS:** My OS is Ubuntu 16.04. The compiler is:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Comment: `char path[path_maxlen]={0};`

Comment: @DYZ Alas, does not work for variable length arrays.

Comment: @AlexD That's why I never use variable length arrays... So, `path[0]=0;` it is.

Comment: Note that the length argument to `strncat()` is _not_ the total space in the target string but the space left.  If it were not for the small sizes here, you could have buffer overflow. It's why `strncat()` is dangerous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
strncat(path, dirname, path_maxlen - 1);
```

`path` is uninitialized, so it is undefined behavior.

Try

```
char path[path_maxlen];
path[0] = 0; // since path is VLA, usual "={0}" initialization does not work
```

Or you can consider using just `strcpy_s`.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. Will `char path[path_maxlen] = NULL;` also work or are there any caveats to that approach?

Comment: Hmm... Does it compile :-)?

Comment: I accidentally edited and compiled the backup file of the program but then compiled the unedited file. So the changes seemed fine :-). However, after noticing my error I edited the correct file and neither the `{0}` nor the `NULL` version compiles.

Comment: @nautical, `{0}` should work. You should post the error message.

Comment: The error is: `error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
   char path[path_maxlen] = {0};`